I can't use Flower's Partitioning Object for Local Data(ChosenPartitione)
I'm trying to open a local dataset that I generated in image format, but Visual studio is already displaying an error message for the line of code below:
from flwr_datasets.partitioner import ChosenPartitioner
The error message :
ImportError: cannot import name ‘ChosenPartitioner’ from ‘flwr_datasets.partitioner

from datasets import Image, load_dataset
from flwr_datasets.partitioner import ChosenPartitioner

I tried reinstalling the versions available on Pyp
flwr-datasets 0.1.0 using flwr_datasets-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl, but it still doesn't work.

Hi @Carlos De Jesus Reis,The ImportError you're seeing indicates a possible problem with the flwr_datasets library or its installation. Make sure that flwr_datasets is properly installed and that you're using the correct version. Occasionally, documentation or examples might be outdated, leading to discrepancies in the module's content. Verify the available classes and functions in the flwr_datasets package to ensure compatibility.

The ChosenPartitioner is not a literal implementation that is available to use in your code. It is a placeholder for any of the available ("chosen" by you) objects = Partitioners. Therefore the name "Chosen" + "Partitioner" (the name of the base abstraction). All the names are created in that manner e.g. IidPartitioner or DirichletPartitioner.
Here's a list of the available implementations: https://flower.ai/docs/datasets/ref-api/flwr_datasets.partitioner.html#module-flwr_datasets.partitioner.
You can also create a custom Partitioner by subclassing the Partitioner.
Hope that helps!
